# Single query append

Tags: powerquery

I have the following table:

```
 Month | Perc% | FYTD%
 01/01 |    5% |    5%
 01/02 |   10% |  7.5%
 01/03 |    5% |    6%
```

I need to re-arrange it to get:

```
 Month | Perc%
 01/01 |    5%
 01/02 |   10%
 01/03 |    5%
 FYTD  |    6%
```

At the moment I'm using two tables in Power Query, one for the monthly figures and one for the FYTD figure, joining them to create the desired output table.

How can I do it with a single query?

Comment: Is the FYTD row just the last value available in your input table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUjAw1DcwVFDSUTJVhRCxOlBRI5CooQFI2FzP1ABJxhiu3gwoGgsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Month = _t, #"Perc%" = _t, #"FYTD%" = _t]),
    Custom1 = Table.Combine( { #"Source", Table.FromRecords({ [Month = "FYTD%", #"Perc%"= List.LastN(Source[#"FYTD%"],1){0}   ]})}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Custom1,{"FYTD%"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't work the syntax of how to use the real source name for the query , say "Input table" instead of the first part of the query "Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WUjAw1DcwVFDSUTJVhRCxOlBRI5CooQFI2FzP1ABJxhiu3gwoGgsA", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate" etc.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. The first line just recreates your sample data. Replace it with your source data.

Comment: Oops, yeah, get it now.  Thanks.